# What is the correct connection string for PostgresSQL remote db on AWS EBS

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, flask

I'm trying to connect my locally hosted flask app to remotely set up RDS DB on Amazon, I'm unable to get my app to access it. It says no password supplied.

Here is what I have done:

- Google
- StackOverflow

Setting the Inbound Rules in EC2 Security Groups for RDS DB to allow all incoming traffic from anywhere.

This is my application.py code:

```
    from os import environ
from Flask_Auth.manage import application

import Flask_Auth.manage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

This is my config.py code:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
postgres_local_base = 'postgresql:///postgres:123123123!@confudb.cusmbtiketg6.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com/confudb'

database_name = 'confudb'
#'postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost/'
#'flask_jwt_auth'

class BaseConfig:
    """Base configuration."""
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'y\n=\xc5\xfa\nB\xb8t\n\x83\xbef\x8a\xe3\xddE\x17\x06\xc9\x96\x8ec|')
    DEBUG = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 13
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    """Development configuration."""
    DEVELOPMENT = True
    DEBUG = True
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 4
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = postgres_local_base
```

I have prod and test configs as well.

I can connect through the pgAdmin in my windows laptop but can't connect my app to it.

I can add the server through add server in pgAdmin and access it to the fullest but somehow I'm unable to connect my application to my remote database.

[image: The console log from the request sent to my local server hosted on 5000 port which probably defaults for a flask applicaiton]

This is what my AWS security policies are:

[image: AWS security inbound rules for RDS databse]

Kindly If any one can resolve this issue that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your URL has an extra `/` in it.

Comment: yes you are right but if i remove it PostMan says that can't parse the url.

Comment: So have to use this got this by another answer here on SOF.

Comment: What happens if you remove it, does the code work? Do you get a different error?